# Why is the generic parameter necessary in CDI?

Tags: glassfish, cdi, java-ee-7, weld

I use Java 1.7 and Glassfish 4.0.

There is a generic interface `Service<T>` with 2 implementations where the second extends the first.

```
public interface Service<T>{
  void serve(T t);
}

@Singleton @ServiceQualifier(type=ServiceType.DEFAULT)
public class DefaultService implements Service<MyType>{
  public void serve(MyType t){
    ...
  }
}

@Singleton @ServiceQualifier(type=ServiceType.SPECIAL)
public class SpecialService extends DefaultService{
  @Override
  public void serve(MyType t){
    ...
  }
}
```

In order to use CDI there is a qualifier annotation where `ServiceType` is a simple enum with `ServiceType.DEFAULT` and `ServiceType.SPECIAL`.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ServiceQualifier {
  ServiceType type();
}
```

If the Service is injected like this

```
@Inject @ServiceQualifier(type=ServiceType.DEFAULT)
private Service service;
```

the CDI Container throws an exception (I deploy the app to glassfish 4 if that matters.)

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type
>   [Service] with qualifiers [@ServiceQualifier]

But if the Service is injected with the generic parameter it works.

```
@Inject @ServiceQualifier(type=ServiceType.DEFAULT)
private Service<MyType> service;
```

I am very confused now because i thought that [generic parameters are removed at compile time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens?lq=1). Can someone explain why it is necessary to specify the generic parameter although it is compiled away?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's required as the type parameter goes into the selection.  You can put the qualifier anywhere , but if it doesn't match type you won't be able to inject the bean into it.

Comment: John is right. Whatsmore generic type erasure does not prevent Weld using reflection at runtime to get the generic parameter types.